# .htaccess/mod_rewrite 301 problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, redirectmode

I have a website with the following `mod_rewrite` rules in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^web-design/case-studies/(.+)/$  work.php?slug=$1  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^web-design/case-studies/        work.php          [L,NC]
```

What I'm wanting to do is set up a 301 redirect for any requests such as `domain.com/web-design` (with or without trailing slash) and redirect to `example.com/web-design/case-studies/` (with trailing slash).

Unfortunately, the combination of `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` rules I've tried seem to conflict with `RewriteRules` I have and end up with a redirect loop.

Regular expressions really isn't my thing, but I'm guessing I'll need a `RewriteMatch` rule to match requests that start with `/web-design` but don't also contain `/case-studies`? How would this be accomplished in `.htaccess`?

Comment: If you already have `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` lines can you please paste them here.

Comment: There are no `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` rules in place, just vanilla `RewriteRule` lines at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try these rules in your .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^web-design/?$ /web-design/case-studies/          [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^web-design/case-studies/?$ /work.php             [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^web-design/case-studies/(.*)$ /work.php?slug=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
```

It is important to use QSA in last rule to not to loose existing QUERY parameters. I have tested these rules and they seem to be working fine. Trailing slash is optional in first 2 rules as per your requirements.